# C# Substring and ToUpper

Tags: c#, substring

I'm using substring and IndexOf to locate a value within a string but my code doesn't work if the string (strOldValue) below contains any of the string in a different case. So if strOldValue contained Test or TEST then my substring fails. How would I add ToUpper in this scenario? Forgive my ignorance I'm new to .Net.

```
String strValue = strOldValue.Substring(strOldValue.IndexOf(@"test"));
```

Thanks
C

Answer (score 17):

Using ToUpper, it would be done like this:

```
String strValue = strOldValue.Substring(
                    strOldValue.ToUpper().IndexOf(@"TEST"));
```

However, the easiest would be to specify that the comparison should not be done case-sensitive:

```
String strValue = strOldValue.Substring(strOldValue.IndexOf(@"TEST",
          StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

The second *comparisonType* parameter of the *IndexOf* method specifies how to search for the value parameter: using the current or invariant culture, using a case-sensitive or case-insensitive search, or using word or ordinal comparison rules (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx for the full documentation).

Comment: I'm merging my answer with yours. If you don't like it, roll it back. I think ours combined is the best

Comment: I edited to avoid Horizontal scroll bars -  please rollback if you don't like .

Answer (score 3):

```
String strValue 
    = strOldValue.Substring(strOldValue.ToUpper().IndexOf(@"TEST"));
```

Note: I'm answering the question directly as asked ("How would I add ToUpper in this scenario?").

This is NOT how I would code a case-insensitive substring.

The answer by divo/TheSoftwareJedi is clearly superior.

Comment: Note: I'm answering the question directly as asked ("How would I add ToUpper in this scenario?"). This is NOT how I would code a case-insensitive substring.

Comment: Perhaps putting how you would code it would help.  Sometimes the n00b questions aren't asked perfectly you know ;)

Answer (score 2):

Using the `String.IndexOf(String,StringComparison)` is probably the best answer. Using `ToUpper()` in there someplace just creates an extra String object that has to be destroyed by Garbage Collector. Almost all the String comparison methods have an overload that accepts a flag that states how to do comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

```
strValue.Substring(strValue.IndexOf("TEST", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 0):

As an regular expressions fan, I would use the following code:

```
String strValue = new Regex("test.*",
       RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Match(strOldValue).Value;
```